# Access elements of paypal response object in php

Tags: php, object, paypal, response

I get paypal response for success object as below.

```
$data = array('PayPalResult'=>$response);
print_r($data);
```

When I check with `print_r` I get the following data in there. 
But having trouble to access the details from the object array, please help. I tried as below code, but getting error saying could not convert to string, I searched a lot and tried, but nothing worked.

```
Array ( [PayPalResult] =>
      Merchant_payflow_pro_response Object ( [_response:protected] => 
        Array ( [RESULT] => 0 
                [PNREF] => A11R7C40C51D
                [RESPMSG] => Approved 
                [AUTHCODE] => 000674 
                [CVV2MATCH] => Y ) 
                [_status:protected] => complete [_message:protected] => Approved 
                [_reference:protected] => A11R7C40C51D [_data:protected] =>  
                [_redirect_url:protected] => 
                [_redirect_method:protected] => GET 
                [_redirect_message:protected] => 
                [_redirect_data:protected] 
          => ) )

 foreach (array('PayPalResult'=>$response) as $k => $v) 
  { // if $v is an Array, appllies another foreach() loop to it, to get its elements
              if(is_array($v)) {
                foreach ($v as $key => $val) {
                  echo '<br />'. $k. ' - '. $key. ' : '. $val;
                  if ($key == 'RESPMSG')
                  $data['msg'] = $val;
                  else if ($key == 'PNREF')
                  $data['ref'] =  $val;
                  else if($key == 'RESULT')
                  $data['result'] = $val;
                  else if($key == 'AUTHCODE')
                  $data['authcode'] = $val;
                  else if($key == 'CVV2MATCH')
                  $data['cvv2match'] = $val;
                 } 
  }//else echo '<br />'. $k. ' - '. $v;}
```

it's not going inside is_array(), so nothing happens. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to get the transaction reference and the message. I used the below code.
print_r($response->reference());
print_r($response->message());
But I can't access the array having the payment variables.

Found an alternate way by getting the needed values inside the class constructor and retrieving them from the object like above method.
For ex to get AUTHCODE value I wrote the code print_r($response->_authcode);
To have this carry value inside the constructor got authcode as 
$this->_authcode = $this->_response['AUTHCODE'];

Problem solved.